# Air Bearing pressure vs area

Tags: air

I'm interested in hovering 100 lbs.

I'm interested in knowing what pressure of air and what surface area is needed and how they relate to each other.

Comment: $F = P*A$ where $F$ is force, $P$ is pressure and $A$ is area.

Comment: How many degrees of freedom?

Comment: Try googling "air bearing design guide" to get an idea of the parameters.  It's not just the pressure, but also the airflow rate, etc, which depend on your geometry and what kind of performance you need.  Other keywords you might use with "air bearing" are application, selection, hydrostatic, calculation, guidelines, tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need $444.52016 N$ force to support that load, and that force is given as force $F=P*A$,
where $P$ is the pressure of air and $A$ is the area of the supporting platform. Please use whatever value for $P$ and $A$ is convenient for you.